# Merging Two JSON Documents Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to merge two JSON documents with the Jackson JSON library? I am basically using the Jackson mapper with simple Java Maps.

I've tried to search in Google and Jackson's documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One way is to use `ObjectReader` like so:

```
MyBean defaults = objectMapper.readValue(defaultJson, MyBean.class);
ObjectReader updater = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(defaults);
MyBean merged = updater.readValue(overridesJson);
```

which will combine data from two sources. This only makes a shallow copy, i.e. does not do recursive merge on contained objects.

Otherwise you may need to just read JSON as a tree (`JsonNode`), loop over contents and merge manually. This often makes sense anyway since rules of merging are not trivial, and everyone has their own ideas of how merging should work.

**EDIT**: (03-Apr-2017)

As per @Fernando Correia's comment, there is actually a new [feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1399) added in upcoming Jackson 2.9 (to be released in April or May 2017) that does allow deep merging, finally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do need a deep merge, hence you're suggestion to write the merge manually echos the gut feeling I had when I posted the question. My underlying data structures are Maps, hence it should be worth writing a generic deep merge routine for java Maps. It may prove to be re-usable in some future project.

Comment: is deep merge available as a feature now ?

Comment: No, not as of Jackson 2.6.

Comment: It is implemented for the (upcoming) version 2.9: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1399

Comment: @FernandoCorreia well spotted, it is indeed! Thank you for adding an update; I will add an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 75):

Inspired by StaxMans answer I implemented this merging method.

```
public static JsonNode merge(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {

    Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();
    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(fieldName);
        // if field exists and is an embedded object
        if (jsonNode != null && jsonNode.isObject()) {
            merge(jsonNode, updateNode.get(fieldName));
        }
        else {
            if (mainNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
                // Overwrite field
                JsonNode value = updateNode.get(fieldName);
                ((ObjectNode) mainNode).put(fieldName, value);
            }
        }

    }

    return mainNode;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Looks pretty good @Arn! It will be helpful if I need to do this in a future project. When I asked this question, I was working with elasticsearch and I found a partial update plugin for it. That helped me at that time.

Comment: Excellent, Arne, that is exactly what I've needed, you've saved me hours of investigation, thank you. To make this a little more than `thank you` comment, as of Jackson 2.4 `put()` is deprecated and should be substituted with `replace()`. Also, for JDK8 users, the code could be made more concise with trivial invoking of `forEachRemaining()` directly on the iterator and passing in the somewhat shorter lambda-expression.

Comment: great thanks. does this work for embedded arrays? both when adding elements  to the array and when removing elements ? or do we have to replace the whole array?

Answer (score 20):

Inspired by Arn's answer. Editing it to add the case where a node may have a array of nodes in it.

```
public static JsonNode merge(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {

    Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();

    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
        String updatedFieldName = fieldNames.next();
        JsonNode valueToBeUpdated = mainNode.get(updatedFieldName);
        JsonNode updatedValue = updateNode.get(updatedFieldName);

        // If the node is an @ArrayNode
        if (valueToBeUpdated != null && valueToBeUpdated.isArray() && 
            updatedValue.isArray()) {
            // running a loop for all elements of the updated ArrayNode
            for (int i = 0; i < updatedValue.size(); i++) {
                JsonNode updatedChildNode = updatedValue.get(i);
                // Create a new Node in the node that should be updated, if there was no corresponding node in it
                // Use-case - where the updateNode will have a new element in its Array
                if (valueToBeUpdated.size() <= i) {
                    ((ArrayNode) valueToBeUpdated).add(updatedChildNode);
                }
                // getting reference for the node to be updated
                JsonNode childNodeToBeUpdated = valueToBeUpdated.get(i);
                merge(childNodeToBeUpdated, updatedChildNode);
            }
        // if the Node is an @ObjectNode
        } else if (valueToBeUpdated != null && valueToBeUpdated.isObject()) {
            merge(valueToBeUpdated, updatedValue);
        } else {
            if (mainNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
                ((ObjectNode) mainNode).replace(updatedFieldName, updatedValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return mainNode;
}
```

Comment: The casting of `valueToBeUpdated` to an `ArrayNode` is not safe. You can get a `TextNode`, for instance, instead of an `ArrayNode` in that variable.

Comment: Thanks PNS. I have edited my answer and added the condition to check if valueToBeUpdated is an arrayNode

Comment: Cool - but doesn't work if updateNode starts with an ArrayNode, because they do not have fields, just children.  BTW - ObjectReader updating work for me.

Comment: Thanks to you I'm going to sleep more hour today, thank you my friend!! :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. Works like a charm. Btw it doesn't work if root node is JSONArray, so I just modified the code by copying while-loop's ArrayNode code at top level in if-else

Answer (score 6):

Below is an implementation in Scala. The source and target node are mostly commutative except when a branch exists in both source and target.

```
  def mergeYamlObjects(source: ObjectNode, target: ObjectNode, overwrite: Boolean = true): ObjectNode = {
    if (target == null)
      source
    else if (source == null)
      target
    else {
      val result = source.deepCopy
      val fieldlist = source.fieldNames.asScala.toList ++ target.fieldNames.asScala.toList
      for (item <- fieldlist) {
        if (!(source has item)) {
          result put(item, target get item)
        } else {
          if ((source get item).isValueNode) {
            if (target has item)
              if (overwrite)
                result.put(item, target get item)
          } else {
            result.put(item, mergeYamlObjects(source.get(item).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode],
              target.get(item).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode], overwrite = overwrite))
          }
        }
      }
      result
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If someone simply wants to add two or more JsonNode object into one JsonNode, this can be one approach:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
arrayNode.add(firstJsonNode);
arrayNode.add(secondJsonNode);
arrayNode.add(thirdJsonNode);

JsonNode root = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
((ObjectNode) root).put("", arrayNode);
System.out.println("merged array node #: " + root);
```

Comment: The method put(String, JsonNode) from the type ObjectNode is deprecated   , use set or replace

Answer (score 3):

Here,is full implementation of merging two JSON  tree into one. Hope it would be helpful :)

```
/**
 * Merge two JSON tree into one i.e mergedInTo.
 *
 * @param toBeMerged
 * @param mergedInTo
 */
public static void merge(JsonNode toBeMerged, JsonNode mergedInTo) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> incomingFieldsIterator = toBeMerged.fields();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> mergedIterator = mergedInTo.fields();

    while (incomingFieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> incomingEntry = incomingFieldsIterator.next();

        JsonNode subNode = incomingEntry.getValue();

        if (subNode.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.OBJECT)) {
            boolean isNewBlock = true;
            mergedIterator = mergedInTo.fields();
            while (mergedIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = mergedIterator.next();
                if (entry.getKey().equals(incomingEntry.getKey())) {
                    merge(incomingEntry.getValue(), entry.getValue());
                    isNewBlock = false;
                }
            }
            if (isNewBlock) {
                ((ObjectNode) mergedInTo).replace(incomingEntry.getKey(), incomingEntry.getValue());
            }
        } else if (subNode.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.ARRAY)) {
            boolean newEntry = true;
            mergedIterator = mergedInTo.fields();
            while (mergedIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = mergedIterator.next();
                if (entry.getKey().equals(incomingEntry.getKey())) {
                    updateArray(incomingEntry.getValue(), entry);
                    newEntry = false;
                }
            }
            if (newEntry) {
                ((ObjectNode) mergedInTo).replace(incomingEntry.getKey(), incomingEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
        ValueNode valueNode = null;
        JsonNode incomingValueNode = incomingEntry.getValue();
        switch (subNode.getNodeType()) {
            case STRING:
                valueNode = new TextNode(incomingValueNode.textValue());
                break;
            case NUMBER:
                valueNode = new IntNode(incomingValueNode.intValue());
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                valueNode = BooleanNode.valueOf(incomingValueNode.booleanValue());
        }
        if (valueNode != null) {
            updateObject(mergedInTo, valueNode, incomingEntry);
        }
    }
}

private static void updateArray(JsonNode valueToBePlaced, Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> toBeMerged) {
    toBeMerged.setValue(valueToBePlaced);
}

private static void updateObject(JsonNode mergeInTo, ValueNode valueToBePlaced,
                                 Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> toBeMerged) {
    boolean newEntry = true;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> mergedIterator = mergeInTo.fields();
    while (mergedIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = mergedIterator.next();
        if (entry.getKey().equals(toBeMerged.getKey())) {
            newEntry = false;
            entry.setValue(valueToBePlaced);
        }
    }
    if (newEntry) {
        ((ObjectNode) mergeInTo).replace(toBeMerged.getKey(), toBeMerged.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , maybe is better to use a deepCopy on each getValue ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to concatenate two JSONs, the simplest way I found is the following (considering you have two ObjecNode ready):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Dummy objects to concatenate
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
map.put("k", "v");

Map<String, Object> secondMap = new HashMap();
secondMap.put("secondK", "secondV");

//Transforming Objects into ObjectNode
ObjectNode firstObjectNode = mapper.convertValue(map, ObjectNode.class);
ObjectNode secondObjectNode = mapper.convertValue(secondMap, ObjectNode.class);

//Concatenating secondObjectNode into firstObjectNode
firstObjectNode.setAll(secondObjectNode);

//Output will be: {"k":"v","secondK":"secondV"}
System.out.println(firstObjectNode);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Merge **json -> json** with [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
@SneakyThrows
public static String mergeToPretty(String baseJson, String overrideJson) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    Object base = objectMapper.readValue(baseJson, Object.class);
    Object merged = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(base).readValue(overrideJson);
    return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(merged);
}
```

Notes:

- `@SneakyThrows` could be replaced with exception handling if not using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).
- If no need for pretty, remove `.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` from last line.