# Java - Merge JSON files

Tags: java, json

I am building an updater util that update my application.
I need to save my configuration files from the previous version.
Some of the configurations files are JSON files.
Is there a way to update the JSON files in a way that i'm keeping the old values
but if there new objects or keys they will be saved also?

For example:
Version 1 json file:

```
{
    "name": "demo",
    "description": "Parse some JSON data",
    "location": "New York"
}
```

Version 2 json file:

```
{
    "name": "demo",
    "description": "Parse some JSON data",
    "location": "London",
    "day": "Monday"
}
```

Expected json file after the merge:

```
{
    "name": "demo",
    "description": "Parse some JSON data",
    "location": "New York",
    "day": "Monday"
}
```

Is there a way to do so without any external library?

Comment: are you using any JSON library or you're writing JSON by hand?

Comment: Currently I'm not using JSON library, The JSON's given to me as files, i don't know how they written originally.

Comment: Use a library. Put both into a Hashmap. Rebuild JSON object

Comment: Unless you instead want `"location": ["New York", "London"]`, then it becomes more complicated

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895041/merging-two-json-documents-using-jackson ?

Comment: @cricket_007 i did as a you advised and its worked, Thanks!

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak i did look at this post, but my question is more specific, and off curse, there the part of doing so without library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @cricket_007 advised, This solution worked for me:

```
public void mergeJsonsFiles(File newJson, File oldJson) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, Object> newMap = convertJsonToMap(newJson);
    HashMap<String, Object> oldMap = convertJsonToMap(oldJson);

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : oldMap.entrySet()) {
        if (newMap.get(entry.getKey()) == null) {
            newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonFromMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(newMap);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newJson);
    writer.write(jsonFromMap);
    writer.close();
}

private HashMap<String, Object> convertJsonToMap(File json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        map.clear();
    }
    return map;
}
```