# MapStruct: Fields from Different Entities mapping to Same Entity Different fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have Class A, B and C. Class A has three variables and it gets populated based on different fields of Class B and C. When I use mapper to populate object only last used mapper values are retained. How can I make sure that all values are populated.
    I am using MapStruct mapper(version 1.2.0) with Spring Boot version 2.0.3

```
Sample code below:
Class A{

  String a;
  String b;
  String c;

  }

Class B{
 String b1;
}

Class C{
    String c1;
}

public interface AtoCmapper{
  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="c", source="source.c1")
  })
  A CtoA(C source);

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="c1", source="source.c")
  })
  C AtoC(A source);
}

public interface AtoBmapper{
  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="b", source="source.b1")
  })
  A BtoA(B source);

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="b1", source="source.b")
  })
  B AtoB(A source);
}

Class DAO{

 @Autowired
 AtoBmapper aToBMapper;

 @Autowired
 AtoCmapper aToCMapper;

 public void testMapping(){
  A aObject = new A();

  aObject = aToBMapper(bObject); // Assume bObject is object to Type B and it is initialized properly

  aObject = aToCMapper(cObject); // Assume cObject is object to Type B and it is initialized properly
 }

 //Now when I call testMapping() resulting A object only has value set for variable c, value of b is lost.
 How can I make sure that Values from B and C are set properly to Class A
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapStruct can [update existing instances](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances)!
To do this, introduce new mapping methods (or replace the old ones) by variants which have a second `@MappingTarget` annotated parameter of the type `A` (and in this case one may replace the return type by `void`):

```
// In AtoBmapper
@Mappings(...)
void updateAFromB(B source, @MappingTarget A target);

// In AtoCmapper
@Mappings(...)
void updateAFromC(C source, @MappingTarget A target);
```

Then you can write:

```
A aObject = new A();

aToBMapper.updateAFromB(bObject, aObject);
aToCMapper.updateAFromC(cObject, aObject);

// now aObject should contain the cumulated data from b and c
```

Comment: any idea similar method available in jackson that reads string into object that is already available?

Comment: Googling "Jackson update existing object" gave me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895041/merging-two-json-documents-using-jackson

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks, Looks to me it may serve my purpose.