# Can Jackson be used to update a POJO?

Tags: java, jackson

The most generic way to convert from JSON to Java objects is to capture the JSON as a `Map<String, Object>`. From this (or directly) I can convert to a POJO easily:

```
User user = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonMap, User.class);
```

Any `User` fields that were not present in the original JSON will be set to their default values. While this is great for *creating* new objects (in response to (say) an API call), it doesn't work for *updating* a POJO.

What I want to achieve is to *update* an existing `User` object from incoming JSON using Jackson. This means:

1. Properties in the incoming JSON (that are also fields in the POJO) are used to update (overwrite) the corresponding fields in the POJO.
2. Properties in the incoming JSON that are **not** fields in the POJO are ignored.
3. Fields in the `User` POJO that don't have any corresponding properties in the incoming JSON are left alone.

Is this possible with Jackson?

Comment: you could create a map from your initial user, then merge it with the one from json and at last create a new `User` from the merged map

Comment: Have a look at [`json-patch`](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch)

Comment: The Jackson [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) has a factory method [readerForUpdating](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating(java.lang.Object)) that should do this (I didn't test it, but from the API I would suggest that it's what you need). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9912406/8178842) for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`readerForUpdating`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating(java.lang.Object)) to create an `ObjectReader`

> Factory method for constructing ObjectReader that will update given Object (usually Bean, but can be a Collection or Map as well, but NOT an array) with JSON data.

and then use the [`readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue(java.lang.String)) on the `ObjectReader`:

> Method that binds content read from given JSON string, using configuration of this reader. Value return is either newly constructed, or root value that was specified with `withValueToUpdate(Object)`.

in a code similar to this one:

```
  ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(objectToUpdate);
  MyType objectUpdated = objectReader.readValue(inputJson);
```

Comment: You forgot to format-as-code some of your code (the one related to existing employee) . Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @markvgti yes sorry :D