# Merge several json objects Java with jackson

Tags: java, json, merge, jackson

I use a java delegate and use the getVariable to read the execution variables. Within the execution variables, I have many stringified JSON objects. I loop through all the objects and read create a json node in the following way,

```
for (String name: execution.getVariableNames()) {
    JsonNode data = objectMapper.readTree(execution.getVariable(name).toString());
    System.out.println(data);
 }
```

I get all the individual JSON objects from the above for loop.

```
{"username": "testUser", "company": "TestCompany"}
{"app": "testApp", "subscriberCount": 20000}
{"appCount": 20}
```

The above is an example of the output I receive. What I would like is to combine the above json objects to a single json objects within the loop. The output should be something like this.

```
{
   "username": "testUser",
   "company": "TestCompany",
   "app": "testApp",
   "subscriberCount": 20000,
   "appCount": 20
}
```

I want to merge all the objects dynamically. Which means I don't want to consider the data that are in the json objects when merging them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could produce a new object and iterate over the fields in your existing data objects to assign them to the new object.

[This existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11459962/3053430) shows how to merge objects by iterating over their fields. It performs a deeper-level merge, but to simply merge top-level keys you might do something like this for each `data` object to put their fields into a single `ObjectNode`:

```
ObjectNode merged = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
for (String name: execution.getVariableNames()) {
    JsonNode data = objectMapper.readTree(execution.getVariable(name).toString());
    data.fields()
        .forEachRemaining(f -> merged.putIfAbsent(f.getKey(), f.getValue()));
}
```

(The `forEachRemaining` line is the relevant one to add keys from one object to another in this case.)