# Call JsonProperty setter method from a dependent class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
   @JsonProperty("my_id")
   private String id;

   @JsonProperty("my_list")
    private List<SecondClass> myList;

   public getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public getMyList() {
      return this.myList;
   }

   public setMyList(List<SecondClass> myList) {
      this.myList = myList;
   }
}
```

My class has a dependency on another class called SecondClass [through the List entity]

```
public class SecondClass {
   @JsonProperty("my_name")
   private String name;

   public getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

I know how to access the getters and setters of **"MyClass"** using Reflection based on the **JsonProperty** name, as shown below:

```
public void myMethod(MyClass myClass, String jsonProperty, String newId) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        JsonProperty jsonPropAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
        if (jsonPropAnnotation != null)
            if (jsonPropAnnotation.value().equals(jsonProperty)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(myClass, newId);
            }
    }
}
```

But, my question is, is there a way to fetch the getter and setter from **SecondClass** via **MyClass** based on the JsonProperty name using Reflection?

*As an example I would like to call getList() based on JsonProperty value "my_list" and then setName() based on the JsonProperty value "my_name".*

Is this a possibility using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve and how you will pass the values to set but all this is possible. Please check below code piece for your problem.
If you can explain me the full requirement then may be I can help you in implementing the best solution but for this ask below code will also work -

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    List<SecondClass> secondClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    myClass.setId("1234");
    SecondClass sc1 = new SecondClass();
    sc1.setName("Name1");
    secondClasses.add(sc1);

    myMethod(myClass, "my_id", "1234");
    System.out.println(myClass.getId());
    for (SecondClass secondClass : secondClasses) {
        SecondClass secondClass1 = new SecondClass();
        myMethod(secondClass1, "my_name", secondClass);
        System.out.println(secondClass1.getName());
    }

}

public static void myMethod(Object object, String jsonProperty, Object value) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        JsonProperty jsonPropAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
        if (jsonPropAnnotation != null)
            if (jsonPropAnnotation.value().equals(jsonProperty)) {
                if (field.getType().equals(String.class) || field.getType().equals(Double.class)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    if (value.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
                        field.set(object, value);
                    }else{
                        field.set(object, field.get(value));
                    }
                }

            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So I have a list of "SecondClass" objects. I need to access the getter method of this list using its JsonProperty name [Reflection]. Once I have this list of SecondClass objects, I will fetch the first entry and call the setter method of "name" field of SecondClass by using its JsonProperty using reflection. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: so If I am not wrong you have a object of MyClass and you have to create another object of MyClass by using reflections and jsonproperty where in object you have field names may be different but jsonproperty will be same so that you can construct a new object, is it right ?

Comment: No I have an object of MyClass. I will fetch the list entry of MyClass by calling its getter method using its JsonProperty name using Reflection. This is a list of SecondClass objects. Let us assume the list only has 1 entry. I now need to call the setter method of name field using its JsonProperty name [reflection].

Comment: **Basically, use reflection to call getter method of a list of objects using its JsonProperty value. The call the setter method using reflection, of the first object from the list by using the field's JsonProperty name.**

Comment: so that means you will call myMethod somehow like this- myMethod(List<SecondClass> output, "my_list", List<SecondClass> input); and you want to put data from input list into output list based on jsonproperty from Second class, right ?

Comment: Yes. Let us say I got the List [using reflection]. Then I fetch the first entry of the list [which is of type SecondClass]. I need to call the setName() method of SecondClass using the JsonProperty value of the field "name".

Comment: I have updated the solution as per your requirement as per my understanding, you can let me know if  you requirement something else.